# How to show traffic information on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, bing-maps, traffic

I am trying to create a simple app in WP7 which will show traffic information using Bing Map control. I have tried to find some information on google without success.
As I know bing id giving **Geocode, Imagery, Route** and **Search** services, non of which can do this work.
Is it possible to get traffic information?
Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no Bing Maps service to retrieve or display traffic information.

The Route service will generate an optimal route accounting for traffic usage (based on the supplied TrafficUsage property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980851.aspx) but it does not expose the traffic data in any form

There are plenty of providers that do provide traffic information. In the UK, for example, the Highways Agency provide RSS feeds that you can subscribe to and create a shapelayer in Bing Maps to show various incidents etc. - http://www.highways.gov.uk/traffic/17629.aspx

If you want to use traffic information in a commercial app you should expect to have to pay for it.

Comment: Thanks @Alastair for answer. Traffic was needed to generate optimal rote. As Route service can do that, I will use it.